# PhoneGap Windows Phone app failed to resume

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova

my app build with phonegap running on Windows phone 7, it works fine. But I find that it failed to resume from device sleep mode. What should I do to debug this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you running it in debug-mode with your developer-unlocked phone? In that case, you should have the stacktrace.

Comment: Where can i find the stacktrace? Thanks.

Comment: If you run your application in debug-mode from Visual Studio, you should get more information about the crash, when it happens.

Answer (score 0):

You should familiarise yourself with the [WP7 app lifecycle](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/10/a-windows-phone-7-1-mango-mvvm-tombstoning-example/)  - PhoneGap apps can be suspended / resumed automatically, i.e. you do not need to write any code. However, when they are tombstoned you need to save the state. See this blogpost for details:

http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/10/tombstoning-with-phonegap-for-windows-phone-7-and-knockoutjs/